# How do I call a function inside of another function in C++?

Tags: c++, function, forward-declaration

How do I call a function inside of another function in C++?

Comment: You need to give examples, code, something to help everyone understand what you are trying to ask.

Comment: You don't think _what_ is possible? Solve _what_? What do you mean by "use"?

Comment: Do you mean declare a function inside a function or just call another function?

Comment: And why is your question tagged C? It's just about C++, right?

Comment: @Mat: Best to train the OP to think about it himself, methinks.

Comment: It doesn't matter whether I have a code sample or not. This question is about only functions, not variables or what the functions contain. // I mean call, not declare xiao // This question is tagged C and C++, because there might be a C++ specific only syntax that allows a function to be called inside another function. Who knows?

Comment: It's quite amazing that you have convinced yourself this is impossible, when in fact is very easy. Unless you post the code that you are trying, no-one is going to be able to understand why you are finding it so difficult.

Comment: reopened. This is a real question.

Comment: @desbest: Right, so C has nothing to do with it, so this question should not be tagged C at all. And, yes, a code sample _does_ matter.

Comment: @Johannes: No offence but are you on drugs!?

Comment: does calling any function from `main` (hint: `main` is a function) count as calling a function from another function? You may already had achieved the impossible!

Comment: Never mind. I fixed my code by moving the function that was being called, above the function that called it. Searching Google said that calling a function inside another function is impossible in C++. By the way, I coded a Battleships game with no functions or classes. Did people close my question as `not a real question` because they just see 1 sentence describing my question and not bother to read it?

Comment: Wow, just wow. Learn about prototypes, learn not to make unwarranted assumptions, above all learn how to ask questions to get the best help possible in SO.

Comment: @desbest, I suspect that the thing you read on google said that **defining** a function inside another function is not possible in C++. Defining a function is not the same as **using** a function, and you misunderstood.

Comment: Yes it did that and everything. It was a 2 player battleships game, that has validation for when you use the same move twice or input something that isn't a move. It lets you quit the game as well. I also did a 1 player version where the cpu competed against the player to see who could sink whose battleships first. There was also validation in the beginning for placing your battleships down, and the cpu remembered where it had played before. The game had nothing overlooked in yet, but still had no classes or functions. My Tic Tac Toe one now I'm doing, has functions.

Comment: You're right. In fact, all the results Google gave me were all asked in an ambiguous manner.

Comment: I think he's trying to implement a function inside another.

Comment: @tomalak huh? How is asking how to use a function inside of another function not a question? You even upvoted a valid answer to it. There is no answer if there is no question.

Comment: I looked again to make sure and the Google results specifically said that it wasn't possible. That's weird.

Comment: @desbest, could you post a link, thanks.

Comment: @desbest: Okay to sort this out, Do you want to call one function inside another function, as FredOverflow's answer suggests or do you want to define a function inside the body of another function?

Comment: I used scanf() :( I learnt that scanf is outdated and impractical, as if you enter something that's not applicable to the type it wants (enter a letter when asked for an integer), what would happen is an infinite loop. I was going to switch from scanf to fgets but I ran out of time. It's nice that C++ doesn't have such stupid things in it.

Comment: I was asking about calling functions. I've updated the question title to reflect this.

Comment: @Johannes: The original wording was nowhere near answerable in itself. Fred took a fair wild stab in the dark and produced a good answer out of it. That doesn't mean that the question really existed. I can give you an answer right now to questions that you haven't asked me yet; it's not hard!

Comment: Okay I'll keep that in mind for future reference. It looks like I'll complete my Tic Tac Toe game today, and most likely not have any more C++ questions again.

Comment: I highly doubt finishing a Tic Tac Toe clone will clear all C++ doubts...

Comment: It's only for coursework. I won't be needing C for anything drastic. Most people on my university course failed the battleships coursework.

Comment: If you "don't think" something is possible because of something you found with Google, you need to **show us the thing you found with Google** so we can explain it properly.

Answer (score 18):

> I don't think this is possible.

I disagree:

```
void bar()
{
}

void foo()
{
    bar();   // there, I use bar inside foo
}
```

If you want to use a function that hasn't been defined yet, you must declare it before you can use it:

```
void baz();   // function declaration

void foo()
{
    baz();
}

void baz()    // function definition
{
}
```

Comment: @BrainStorm: If you read the comments of the question it turns out that this is exactly what the OP wanted to know. So I doubt this is sarcasm. It is the correct answer to the question that was asked.

Answer (score 1):

you can do so by using `lambda`, new feature on the new standard C++0x

```
int main()
{
    auto square = [&](int x) { return x*x; };
    auto a = square(3);
    return 0;
}
```

http://www2.research.att.com/~bs/C++0xFAQ.html#lambda

Comment: He's not talking about defining a function inside another function, he's talking about using a function inside another function.